# Adding Embedded HTML to Email Messages in Django

Tags: python, django, html-email

I'm trying to add an Embedded HTML to an Email to send an Image in it, but image doesn't seem to appear in here, I reviewed another solutions but nothing seems to result

views:

```
img_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'Mods\Surveys\static\images\Survey.jpg')
print(img_path)
html_content = render_to_string('email_template.html', {
    'survey': survey,
    'url': survey.url,
    'path': img_path,
})

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject=survey.subject,
    body=strip_tags(html_content),
    from_email='my email',
    to=[respondant.email]
)
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ survey.subject}}</h1>
    <p>{{ survey.body}}</p>
    <a href="{{ url }}"><img src="{{ path }}" alt="Image"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Email is sent with subject body and the url, but image doesn't appear
As I said, I reviewed another solutions but nothing seems to help

Answer (score 0):

If this is not working at production:

It's because `static` and `media` categories are handled by Apache external settings, and every project file is not available as "just file". So, you will not access it.

Either:

The file is not placed under static nor media folder, so the site can't resolve it. You need to pass the whole relative path and place file correctly so it will be:

```
Mods\Surveys\static\images\Survey.jpg
```

Or:

```
static\images\Survey.jpg
```

Passing absolute path in template for picture is never a way to go, and if you consider putting it on dedicated server / VPS you never should resolve absolute paths.

Comment: added relative path, but still not working :/